# Does Germany have a law on foreign influence agents (similar to the US' or Russia's)? Or proposals for something like that?

Tags: law, germany, foreign-interference

It seems it's perfectly legal in Germany for parliamentarians to [have](https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/short_news/german-far-right-mps-to-visit-russian-occupied-eastern-ukraine/) their trips sponsored by a foreign country. And likewise for more run-of-the-mill influencers, [e.g. rally organizers](https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/ukraine-crisis-germany-influencers/).

So, I'm guessing there's no [US-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Agents_Registration_Act) (and more rencelty, also [Russian-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_foreign_agent_law)) registration requirement and self-disclosure for such financing, for people involved in politics or influencing operations? Any proposals/discussions to have something like that enacted? Or is something like that a non-starter in Germany?

Comment: Well, it looks like the AfD is proposing something like that, in order to counter American influence, which they see as excessive https://correctiv.org/aktuelles/neue-rechte/2022/11/23/die-afd-und-die-anbiederung-an-regime-wie-china-russland-und-iran/ But the AfD propsal seems targeted exclusively at NGOs.

Comment: There are laws that members of parliament have to publically disclose any income above some financial threshhold and I would assume a paid trip to a foreign country would count here. However this only says they have to disclose that they received the money, it doesn't prefent them from taking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [Jan. 1st 2022 Germany has a "Lobby Register"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobbyregister#Deutschland), where people and organisations have to register if they want to influence members of parliament or government officials on their own behalf or in a role as professional consultant to a third party. This applies to domestic persons and organizations as well as persons and organizations from other states (there are a few exceptions, e.g. for humanitarian organizations without a permanent address in Germany, details see the "[Lobbyregistergesetz](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/lobbyrg/__2.html)" (German)).

As far as I can tell, this is a lot less draconian regime than the US and Russian laws (failing to register carries a maximum fine of 20 000 Euro rather than getting the organization in question banned or anything like it), but it is the closest thing I could find.

Comment: Do you mean a it is a misdemeanor rather then a felony? A misdemeanor is still punishable by the law.

Comment: @JoeW that is probably what I mean :-). Legal action is limited to paying a fine.

Comment: Well from what I see that isn't the case as you can still serve time or get other penalties there is just an upper limit  on what they can be.

Comment: @JoeW I was trying to translate the German "Ordnungswidrigkeit", which means there is a fine, but you cannot get jailed or otherwise sanctioned.